# How to insert sql query data in array using node js

Tags: javascript, mysql, node.js, arrays

How to insert sql query data  in array using node js
i want to insert data in mysql database and also in array using node js
please give proper solution.

````
var conn = mysql.createConnection({
      host: "localhost",
      user: "root",
      password: "root@123",
      database: "abc"

});
conn.connect(function(err) {
  if (err) throw err;
  console.log("Connected!");
});

var temp = [1, 2];
sql =
  "INSERT INTO  student(`name`, `email`) VALUES (?) ";

conn.query(sql, [temp], function (err, result) {
    console.log(temp);
     if (err) throw err;
     conn.end();
});```
````

Comment: You don't need brackets around the question mark I guess, do `VALUES ?`

Answer (score 0):

Hey please change your code like this...

```
var conn = mysql.createConnection({
      host: "localhost",
      user: "root",
      password: "root@123",
      database: "abc"
});
conn.connect(function(err) {
  if (err) throw err;
  console.log("Connected!");
});

var temp = [1, 2];
var sql =
  "INSERT INTO  student(`name`, `email`) VALUES (?,?) ";

conn.query(sql, temp, function (err, result) {
    console.log(temp);
     if (err) throw err;
     conn.end();
});
```

Comment: this code is insert array data in mysql but i want to insert data in blank or temp  array and if i print the array of variable then  all data are  show

Comment: I can't understand your exact query please provide me more specific about your query so I can help you

Comment: actually, i want to send data from one mysql server to another mysql server using node js after submit data, please help me sir

Comment: you have multiple database connections in same project right?